# Matlab programming dealing with matrix

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I am trying out one of the matlab programming question.

Question:

> Write a function called hulk that takes a row vector v as an input and
>   returns a matrix H whose first column consist of the elements of v,
>   whose second column consists of the squares of the elements of v, and
>   whose third column consists of the cubes of the elements v. For
>   example, if you call the function likes this, A = hulk(1:3) , then A
>   will be [ 1 1 1; 2 4 8; 3 9 27 ].

My Code:

```
function H = hulk(v)
H = [v; v.^2; v.^3];
size(H) = (n,3);
end
```

When I test my code using `A = hulk(1:3)`, it throws an error on console.

```
Your function made an error for argument(s) 0
```

Am I doing something incorrect? Have I missed anything?

Comment: If you want the desired output, use `H = [v; v.^2; v.^3]' ;` and as suggested by Surajeet remove `size(H) = (n,3);`

Comment: Nice function name :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the line `size(H) = (n,3);`
and add the line `H = H';`

Final code should be as follows

```
function H = hulk(v)
    H = [v; v.^2; v.^3];
    H = H';
end
```

Your code giving error in `matlab` editor on the `size(H) = (n,3);` line
[image]

That's why you should use the `matlab`editor itself

Answer (score 2):

For your future reference, you can very easily generalise this function in Matlab to allow the user to specify the number of cols in your output matrix. I also recommend that you make this function a bit more defensive by ensuring that you are working with column vectors even if your user submits a row vector.

```
function H = hulk(v, n)

    %//Set default value for n to be 3 so it performs like your current function does when called with the same signature (i.e. only 1 argument)
    if nargin < 2 %// nargin stands for "Number of ARGuments IN"
        n = 3;
    end if

    %// Next force v to be a row vector using this trick (:)
    %// Lastly use the very useful bsxfun function to perform the power calcs
    H = bsxfun(@power, v(:), 1:n);

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the number of operations using `cumprod`. That way, each `v.^k` is computed as the previous `v.^k` times `v`:

```
function H = hulk(v, n)
H = cumprod(repmat(v,n,1),1);
```

The first input argument is the vector, and the second is the maximum exponent.